# Automatic watt/volt/amp switch

Tags: switches, automation, voltage-detector

Google has failed me so I'm asking here.

I am looking for an automatic switch, which will change state depending on the number of Watts/Volts/Amps flowing through the circuit.

As an example: When the amount of Watts flowing through the switch is less than 40, the switch remains in the default position. When the amount of Watts is greater than 40, it changes position and opens a different circuit.

Does this type of device even exist? (Forgive my ignorance, I am a beginner)

EDIT

**The problem I have:** 
I have the following circuit, where the sensor is generating enough Watts in its off state, that the LEDs turn on even then.

[image]

I am thinking of a workaround like this:

[image]

Where an automatic switch would workaround the issue and only connect the LEDs when the sensor has 'sensed' something.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Do you have fixed voltage in your system?

Comment: @winny I have 230V, but it's AC - does that answer your question? :)

Comment: Yes! You can take a look at one of these. It only turns on one circuit at a given load so if you need to turn off another you need to use a relay to invert that signal. https://theenergychoices.blogspot.com/2017/09/energy-saving-power-strips.html

Comment: @winny Thanks, but I don't think that will work for me. Mostly because I'm looking for something quite small, a little device I can wire in and hide. And it needs to be programmable to turn on at a given amount of power

Comment: *it changes position and opens a different circuit* - what does this mean? Sounds like a recipe for a power oscillator to me.

Comment: Google current/monitoring relay.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you made me realise the flaw in my thinking. I have a motion+sound sensor on a circuit, and LED lamps. The sensor draws enough power in its 'off' state that it turns on the LEDs anyway, so I thought that this kind of switch could work around this issue. However, it is unlikely that the sensor itself will draw more power just because it detected movement, right?...

Comment: Perhaps you should show how you have this sensor and leds wired so we can see what is going on.

Comment: I don't expect you to use it as it, but take inspiration from it. Shunt resistor if DC or current transformer if AC -> filtering -> comparator and you should be well on your way.

Comment: @SolarMike I have updated the question with some visual aids :)

Comment: Regarding your schematics, what kind of a sensor generates power? On the second diagram the sensor is short-circuited when the switch is up. This would be a lot easier if you tell us what the 'sensor' is, what the output voltage and current is, whether it's DC or AC and what the purpose of your indication circuit is.

Comment: You should buy a sensor that has a neutral wire, and connect the neutral wire to neutral. Then it won't let any power through to the LED when it's turned off. Since this is about home lighting you might get better information on diy.stackexchange.com. Also there's no power source in your circuit.

Comment: I assume that this is about home lighting because this *exact* question comes up on diy.stackexchange.com sometimes and there is no other reason for someone to design a sensor that way.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I have looked for that far and wide. There is no other motion+sound sensor which turns on only when it is dark (and is mostly in the wall like this https://www.elking.pl/czujnik-czujka-ruchu-i-dzwieku-do-puszki-fi60-id-357.html) . If there is such a thing out there, please point me towards it. I am only exploring the above options because I haven't been able to find the sensor I need.

Comment: Here is another idea: connect an incandescent bulb in parallel with the LED bulb, or change the LED bulb to an incandescent one. Yes, it wastes power. Maybe the extra bulb doesn't need to be very bright.

Comment: @user253751 A) I can't because the LEDs are mounted into the wall in such a way that adding a light to the circuit would mean I have to take the wall apart

B) It is a waste as you say, and the lights are meant to me night-lights, to turn on when you go pee in the middle of the night. They are purposefully not bright.

Comment: Are you concerned about whether the workaround meets the electrical code? Because the electrical code would probably say: go and buy a sensor with a neutral wire.

Comment: @user253751 AS I said above already. I would LOVE to buy such a sensor. But there isn't one anywhere on the internet. (Or at least not that I could find for many days) If you have a place where I could buy such a sensor with EU delivery, please, throw a link.

Comment: Yeah, over on diy.stackexchange we handle this problem about once a week.  The problem is you're hyperfocused on one *method*, making this an [XY problem]https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  This is a simple problem to solve if you free yourself from that method.

Comment: @Illidanek: There are many questions in the comments that you haven't answered and haven't clarified in your question. This is wasting a lot of time on the part of people trying to answer your question. Please edit your question and explain that the sensor is a two-wire mains powered motion sensor. It doesn't "generate watts" (or anything else). It is intended to switch mains power on and off to control an incandescent lamp. Change your reference to LED to "LED light bulb" so that it is clear what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The crux of the problem

This is a bog-standard problem seen over and over in the DIY stack, when obsolete/cheap dimmers, motion sensors or other smart devices are used with efficient, driver-based LED lighting.

Older *switch loops* do not have a neutral wire.  To solve this problem, older/cheaper, obsolete dimmers, motion sensors and other smart devices use a characteristic of incandescent lights - their extremely low impedance when off.  They leak their operating current through the "off" incandescent filament. This doesn't work on LEDs; they are so efficient they turn *all* current into light.

**The proper way to solve this problem is bring neutral to the switch**, and have the smart switch power itself between supply hot and neutral.  Like a normal load.

### The direct solution

The problem with your idea is you're not allowed to horkle-dorkle "hacks" like this where mains wiring is concerned.  You must follow your local Electrical Code, which says every device must be *approved for use in mains wiring*, and be installed *according to its instructions*.

Here's what you can do: a **relay** that is approved, such as an Aube or RiB.  You wire the hunk-a-junk dimmer in series with a relay coil, with the coil returning to neutral.  Separately (it can even be off a different circuit), you take supply hot to one relay *contact* and connect the other relay contact to the lamp(s).

Now, the relay coil may be too high impedance for your obsolete sensor.  If so, you can add an approved "dummy load" in parallel with the coil, such as the Lutron LUT-MLC, which is approved for this purpose.

It acts like a resistor. Actually, it's a capacitor tuned for your mains frequency.

### Or, just fit the dummy load directly across your lights

Like I say, dummy loads like the Lutron LUT-MLC are designed and approved for the purpose of shunting across LED lights to provide an alternate current path to get obsolete dimmers to work.  *So you could just fit this directly to your lights*.   Problem solved.

This method will work no matter what, even if you have an old-school "switch loop" which has no neutral at the switch. *Never misuse safety ground for neutral, it defeats the purpose of having a ground wire*.

Indeed, one of the diagnostics we give people who report this problem is "Replace one of the bulbs with incandescent, does the problem go away?" The incandescent acts like the dummy load, or to be more precise, the reverse.

### Or get a modern motion sensor

Get a motion sensor that has a neutral wire.  It powers itself via the supply hot and the neutral.  It places no demand on the bulbs at all, and will in fact work properly with no bulbs connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will evaluate all these options. Regarding the last one, I have been trying like crazy to find a motion+sound sensor that turns on when it's dark to absolutely no avail :/ The only one I found is this old-school one.

Comment: @Illidanek Maybe two sensors. A motion sensor that works in the dark should be easy: *that's the entire point of a PIR, when it is pitch black, turn on the light when a human sized infrared source comes into view.*  You can have more than one sensor if it has a neutral or uses a relay.